how to code composite array look up conditions in IBM ODM rules
I have requirement to create a rule with array objects in IBM ODM
And it works good when there is only one such condition like the below..
if the compound code of request is "2" ,
and there is at least one compound area in the compound areas of request where the cmp cvg coverage ind of this compound area is not "P",
then
add message "XYZ" in response
However, I would like to add a composite case to it some thing like below..
But getting syntax error..
if ((the compound code of request is "1"
and the cvg coverage ind of request is not "P")
or
(the compound code of request is "2" ,
and there is at least one compound area in the compound areas of request where the cmp cvg coverage ind of this compound area is not "P")),
then
add message "XYZ" in response
ANy one has a clue what am I doing wrong ?
